# Adding and Deleting from Stack, via Text File Data

Tags: c, file, queue, fgets, fread

I have an assignment where I am to create a main function that takes in a text file (in this case: test.dat) and it is to interpret the file to either add or delete integers from a stack and queue.

I have the stack and queue functioning properly. However, I am not sure how to read the file and have the program actually interpret what it is saying.

For example: If the first line of the file says "add 3", the program will push 3 into the stack and enqueue 3 into the queue. If the next line of the file says "delete", it is to pop the stack and dequeue the queue.

Like I said, the enqueue/dequeue push/pop functions aren't the issue. I do not know how to get my program to actually interpret and distinguish between the integers, characters, and use this info to perform the functions.

sqjuggler.c: (this is the main function to read the file)

```
 #include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sqjuggler.h"
#include "stackADT.h"
#include "queueADT.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

   Stack inStack, outStack;
   Queue inQueue;


  inStack = creates();
  outStack = creates();
  inQueue = createq();


   char *filename;
   if(argc < 2)
   {
        printf("Usage: Enter Filename after ./sqjuggler\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }else if(argc > 2)
   {
        printf("Usage: Entered too many file names.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }else {filename = argv[1];}

   printf("You entered the filename: %s\n", argv[1]);

   FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r+");
   if(fp == NULL)
   {
        printf("Cant open %s\n", filename);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   char str[1000];
   while(fgets(str, 1000, fp) != NULL)
        printf("%s", str);
   fclose(fp);
}
```

Right now, it prints out the text file. Thats all.

Text file:

```
add 3
add 2
delete
add 5
delete
add 10
add 7
delete
add 0
delete
add 11
delete
delete
delete
```

console:

```
xxxxxx:~project2$ make j
gcc  -o j queueADT.c queueADT.h stackADT.c stackADT.h sqjuggler.c sqjuggler.h
xxxxxx:~project2$ ./j test.dat
You entered the filename: test.dat
add 3
add 2
delete
add 5
delete
add 10
add 7
delete
add 0
delete
add 11
delete
delete
delete
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

**EDIT**

I tried to use the strtok function to split the file into tokens. When I implemented this:

```
char *pch;

  pch = strtok(str," \n");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok(NULL, " \n");
  }
```

It only printed an extra "delete"

I am unsure how to get it to split the whole file into tokens and then analyze from there.

**EDIT**

I added this to my while loop and got the following print out:

```
while(fgets(str, 1000, fp) != NULL)
   {
        printf("%s", str);
        char *value = strtok(str, " \n");
        printf("%s", value);
   }
```

console:

```
You entered the filename: test.dat
add 3
addadd 2
adddelete
deleteadd 5
adddelete
deleteadd 10
addadd 7
adddelete
deleteadd 0
adddelete
deleteadd 11
adddelete
deletedelete
deletedelete
```

Comment: If programming a stack is not a problem, then parsing string should be no issue as well. Have you heard of `strstrok`, `sscanf`,  `strsep` etc?

Comment: @Pablo I have only heard of `sscanf` ; however I have not ever implemented it in any code. I haven't heard of the other two before.

Comment: Well, this is the perfect time to read the manuals for this functions. Btw I had a huge typo, it is `strtok`